# Sort array of object

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
array(3) { 
     [0] => object(stdClass)#322 (2) { 
       ["date"]=> string(10) "07-01-2015" 
       ["details"]=> string(191) "Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event Major Event" 
     } 
     [1]=> object(stdClass)#323 (2) { 
       ["date"]=> string(10) "06-01-2015" 
       ["details"]=> string(11) "Major Event" 
     } 
     [2]=> object(stdClass)#324 (2) { 
       ["date"]=> string(10) "14-01-2015" 
       ["details"]=> string(11) "Major Event" 
     } 
}
```

And I want to sort this behalf of date. So how can it possible?

Comment: Which language are you using? And what has this got to do with JSON?

Comment: i am using php with laravel framwork

Comment: If you tag questions with the language you're more likely to get an answer. Still though, what has this got to do with JSON?

Comment: i am getting this JSON through the database. and i want sort this behalf of date(ket of array)

Comment: But it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: yes this is decoded JSON.

Comment: So it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: it's more easy to sort with your sql query, possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the output of a vardump array in php so I'm assuming this is in php you should use usort with a custom comparison function

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a->date);
    $t2 = strtotime($b->date);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
```